authorization scheme on page item in oracle apex
I am trying to authorize page item in apex through authorisation_schema, for this i have created authentication user control in cloud and created authorise schema for that authentication return value as boolean
auth_schema : BFL_SUPER_USER_PREPROD type as "Is In Role or Group"
In page i have added code to chck some more condition along with BFL_SUPER_USER_PREPROD
Dynamic action, when page loads i need to chck either the user has BFL_SUPER_USER_PREPROD access and also the below checks
DECLARE
    l_complete_ind VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
    SELECT COMPLETE_IND
    INTO l_complete_ind
    FROM BFL_CONTAINER_HEADER_V24
    WHERE CONTAINER_ID = :P322_CONTID;
 
    IF l_complete_ind = 'Y'  then
        RETURN TRUE;  -- Enable the button
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE; -- Disable the button
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RETURN FALSE; -- Disable the button if no record is found
END;

What i want is along with the code above i need to include Dynamic action, when page loads i need to chck either the user has BFL_SUPER_USER_PREPROD access and the conditions used in code.
if the condition satisfy then show the button else hide the button

This can be implemented by putting the following attributes on the page item:

authorization scheme BFL_SUPER_USER_PREPROD
server-side condition with the code you posted

If those attributes are on the page item then APEX will decide at page rendering time if the button is rendered or not. For this implementation no dynamic action should be used.
Note, that if a button is hidden this way at page rendering it cannot be shown with a dynamic action because it doesn't exist in the DOM.
